# Do all horizontal-surface mount outlets need to be "floor receptacles?"

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have a horizontal surface that borders a room - basically a wall, but with a 6" jog in it about 4' off the floor that serves as a ledge or shelf.  I'd like to put a couple outlets on this surface.  Would this surface require that I use "floor mount" receptacles (the kind with seals and moisture barriers)?

I get the use of floor receptacles on floors: someone is probably going to run a mop over it at some point, etc.  I could see the possibility *maybe* of someone spilling a drink if they put a glass onto this "shelf".  I'm really trying to understand the Code here; I'm not trying to cut corners.  A floor receptacle would work.  There are more aesthetically-pleasing, cheaper, and easier to install (in my case) options if I'm not required to have one, though.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what code thinks, but I think the outlets would be less in the way and thus more useful on the face of the wall, either above or below the "shelf" - I've lived in a place with one of those. And spills are a real hazard.

Comment: The relevant code section is 406.5E. Also, refer to this question https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109130/can-upward-facing-receptacles-be-installed-flush-to-a-kitchen-island-countertop

Comment: Good link @Ack ... Yes, the problem is any facing-up recep is going to collect dust, drinks and crud into the socket holes.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica True, much like power strips and surge protectors. I try to do regular maintenance via cleaning with a vacuum. The new child safe plates should block must and particles dust from getting deep inside.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in assuming that your ledge is not a floor. The NEC would define it as a work surface or a countertop. That would lead you to NEC 406.5 (E) & (F) which would tell you that the device installation must be GFCI protected and listed for countertop and work surfaces. Most of the ones that I have seen are the pop-up type. A standard flush mount wall receptacle will not work.

FYI. My other concern would be whether or not this 6" ledge top is a 2x6 plate on the top of a frame. Not that it matters code wise but cutting and mounting into it may pose to be a problem. You might want to confirm how this wall was constructed and plan it out before proceeding to cut holes in it.

Good Luck